# Proving $\int_{\Omega} f d\mathbb{P} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \mathbb{P} (f>x)\nu (dx)$

Tags: measure-theory

I can't resolve this, I think use Fubini's theorem, but I can't, help me please. the problem is this,

Positive space measure $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ with $\mathbb{P} = 1$. Suppose $f: (\Omega, F) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$ its a measurable and no negative function with $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{P})$. prove

\begin{equation}\int_{\Omega} f d\mathbb{P} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \mathbb{P} (f>x)\nu (dx)
\end{equation}
with, $\nu$ Lebesgue measure on $B(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: False as stated.  Perhaps you left out a condition?  Say, $f$ is nonnegative?

Comment: yes, sorry, now its correct

Comment: This result together with its proof is easily found by using google. I bet it even is multiple times on this site. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hint: write $P(f > x) = \int_{\Omega} 1_{f(\omega) > x} d \mathbb{P}$.

Comment: I tried with that, but I stop there

Comment: Next interchange the two integrals.

Comment: Yes I tried that too, but how appers f?

Comment: I know how solve this now, thanks, but how can I prove Fubini's hypothesis?

Comment: The function you integrate is non-negative.